# Spring search using Spring Data JPA

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

Im creating a search engine for my web app, but i fell it is too heavy. What can i do?

Lets check what i have tried:

`repository.findAllByProductNameContainingOrProductDescriptionContainingOr...ContainingOr...ContainingOr...ContainingOr...ContainingOr...ContainingOr...ContainingOr...ContainingOr..ContainingOr...(text, text, text ... text);`

It causes a lot of selects in my database and a big method.

What i can i do to prevent this big method?

Is there other method and more efficient to do it?

Comment: please explain question properly.

Comment: @stdunbar i need a help... I dont know too much about search, and im not satisfied with this big method. Please, dont negative it

Comment: Does _big method_ mean the method name is so long?

Comment: Sounds like you are using spring data for your search functionality. As you have discovered, it's the wrong tool for the job. Try bringing another tool like solr and let it index the data for you.

Comment: @Alex you are right!

Comment: @NickHristov you are right too! I will take a look on it! do you have any other ideia?

Comment: How about using JPA with custom query using `@Query` annotation? https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.at-query

Comment: Check out QueryDsl. Spring data repositories have support for it

Comment: Maybe i was not too clear... I was expecting ideia and method of how can i do this search... anyway :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to answer, I created a service which encapsluate this big method name... I know it is not the best way, but this is how i did.